# MySqlDump process very slow

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to create a simple function that I can call to dump a MySql database via mysqldump.exe. The functions works, and it will dump the database, but it is extremely slow. When I run the data export through MySQL Workbench, it will export the database in 1 sec (longest was 4) with the file being just under 14MB. Through my function however, it takes just under 14 min to do the same dump. The database is on my local and is only 31MiB (testing db) according to Workbench.

I call `mysqldump.exe` by creating a new `System.Diagnostics.Process` and attaching a `System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler` to the `OutputDataReceived` event. I also redirected any errors but there have not been any.

Here are the arguements that I am passing to `mysqldump.exe`:

```
String.Format("-h {0} -u {1} -p{2} --port=3306 --max_allowed_packet=1G --no-create-info=TRUE --no-create-db --databases {3}", host, user, pswd, schemaName);
```

Here is the function in its entirety:

```
    StreamWriter _outputStream;

    private void OnDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null) _outputStream.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }

    void OnErrorReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }

    private void CreateBackup(string schemaName)
    {
        string mysqldumpPath = @"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\mysqldump.exe";
        string host = "127.0.0.1";
        string user = "username";
        string pswd = "password";

        string cmd = String.Format("-h {0} -u {1} -p{2} --port=3306 --max_allowed_packet=1G --no-create-info=TRUE --no-create-db --databases {3}", host, user, pswd, schemaName);
        string dumpPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BackupLocation"] + String.Format("\\{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}.sql", 
                                                                                schemaName, DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);

        _outputStream = new StreamWriter(dumpPath);

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = mysqldumpPath;
        startInfo.Arguments = cmd;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(OnErrorReceived);

        proc.Start();

        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

        proc.WaitForExit();

        _outputStream.Flush();
        _outputStream.Close();

        proc.Close();
        _outputStream = null;
    }
```

Is there anything that I should be doing, or could do, that would help this run faster?

Comment: You say you aren't getting error messages -- it looks like you are missing `proc.BeginErrorReadLine()`. You have output reading, but I don't see anything for the error redirects.

Comment: @TyCobb I added the line that you suggested, that was an over site on my part. After adding the line, the only item to return after 3 min of running was `Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`

Comment: Hmm. Only thing I can think of trying is making sure you are using the same arguments as MySql Workbench. According to the screenshot on their export, it shows the exact command line arguments used when it runs mysqldump. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html  I can't think of anything else.

Comment: It is an exact replica except for the password being added and there is no config file